# How to loop through the lines of a .txt file in a bash file?

Tags: bash, matlab, sh, batch-processing

I am trying to run a Matlab script using data from NASA's NSIDC. However, the data is about ~180TB in size so the plan is for me to download one file at a time, run the Matlab script, delete the file.

What I'm planning to do is to write a bash script with something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget file
srun Matlab_Script.m
rm file
```

I can download a `.txt` file that contains the urls for each file I need. How can I loop through each of the urls in the `.txt` file, and run the script like above? Furthermore, how could I save the output in a way where I don't have thousands of `.mat` files each time I run the Matlab script?

I'm new to bash shells so any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You're asking 2 completely different questions, a) "How can I loop through each of the urls in the .txt file, and run the script like above" and b) "how could I save the output in a way where I don't have thousands of .mat files each time I run the Matlab script?", you should ask them separately. to stand the best chance of getting good answers to each from the [probably] separate people who will best know each tool/domain.

Comment: For the first question, see [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).